# VLC command line converting is not always working

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, vlc

I scheduled a `.cmd` file that would convert a network stream into a `.mp4` file, using:

```
vlc -vvv "http://86.127.212.113/control/faststream.jpg?stream=mxpeg" --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=Automat,scodec=none}:file{dst=C:\\Users\\ACV\\Videos\\rec3.mp4,no-overwrite} :no-sout-all :sout-keep
```

It often works, but sometimes it just creates big files that I am not able to play.

Even VLC itself cannot play these files, outputting just [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IavE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the following syntax:

- Replace the `=` after `--sout` with a space character
- Doublequote the `--sout` chain
- Replace the prefix `:` characters for the global options for `no-sout-all` and `sout-keep` with `--`

---

```batch-file
@"%ProgramFiles%\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -vvv "http://86.127.212.113/control/faststream.jpg?stream=mxpeg" --sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=Automat,scodec=none}:file{dst=C:\\Users\\ACV\\Videos\\rec3.mp4,no-overwrite}" --no-sout-all --sout-keep
```

*I have included the full path to `vlc.exe` for safety, please adjust it as you need.*